# Cannot instantiate the type Iterator<ArrayList<Integer>>

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, instantiation

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> wordIndex = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(Collections.<ArrayList<Integer>>nCopies(initWord.length(), null)); 

// Populate it.

Iterator<ArrayList<Integer>> iterWordIndex = new Iterator<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Why can't I do this?

```
 Cannot instantiate the type Iterator<ArrayList<Integer>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot instantiate an `Iterator` because `Iterator` is an interface.  You can only instantiate concrete classes.  In this case, let the `ArrayList` generate one for you:

```
Iterator<ArrayList<Integer>> iterWordIndex = wordIndex.iterator();
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `Iterator` is an interface.  You can't create an instance of it.  You need to create an instance of a concrete class that implements that interface (but most of the time, you just get a reference from an existing collection).